# Generate empty rows for specific years using python

Tags: python, excel

I am missing data for the years 1990-1995 for my data, so I am trying to add empty rows for those years. I need this because used 2 different sources of data and I need to merge them. One has all the years from 1990-2015, but the other has no data for years 1990-1995 for all data points, so I just need to add empty rows for those years. Around 200 countries so I am trying to use python to do it for me, but the code is not working. Can't tell what I am missing.
PyCharm keeps giving "Process finished with exit code 0", but no changes occur.
Code:

```
import openpyxl        
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('gov9.xlsx')   
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

for cell in sheet["A"]:   
    if cell.value == "2015":   
        sheet.insert_rows(idx=cell.row, amount=1)   
wb.save("gov9.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have a problem of casting. Could you try using the following code :

```py
import openpyxl        
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('gov9.xlsx')   
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

for cell in sheet["A"]:   
    if cell.value == 2015:   
        sheet.insert_rows(idx=cell.row, amount=1)   
wb.save("gov9.xlsx")
```

By the way, having exit code = 0 in PyCharm means everything worked as expected :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I tried that already. Exact same thing happens...

Comment: Mmmh it works on my side. Was the file closed when running the script? If yes and a new line still does not appear when reopening it, could you please try to add a `print(cell)` just above your `if` condition, and a `print("condition passed")` into the `if` instruction? That way, we will see if the script enters the condition and if not, why.

Comment: I messed around with it and it worked now. Apparently I was running the wrong file... Shows how new I am to this lol...

Comment: Haha, it happens to everyone! But great idea to learn Python, it will save you a lot of time for that kind of things :)